# Spring Interceptor for BasicDataSource

Tags: spring-mvc, datasource, eclipselink, interceptor, entitymanager

I use the following configuration to connect to my databases (one mysql, one oracle). I am wondering if there is any way to configure a spring interceptor to allow me to audit access to the database and performance of the requests ? Thanks for your input.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>   
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value> 
            <value>${config}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="userEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="userPersistenceUnitManager"/> 
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props> 
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">FINE</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.timestamp">true</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.session">true</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.thread">true</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.exceptions">true</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- See http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html  
-->
<bean id="userDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/> 

    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/> 

    <!-- performance tuning -->
    <property name="initialSize" value="{database.minConnections}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="{database.maxConnections}" /> 
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>

    <!-- The main purpose for the validation here is to avoid reusing a
         expired DB connection -->
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userPersistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/user_persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="userDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not technically related to Spring, there are several `DataSource` decorators that do the job:

- http://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog

  > The goal of the project is to create a high-performance and easy to use tool for the SQL queries logging for JDBC applications.
- http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc

  > log4jdbc is a Java JDBC driver that can log SQL and/or JDBC calls (and optionally SQL timing information) for other JDBC drivers

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz, really looking for an interceptor if possible.